# How does Math.floor( (Math.random() * 10) + 1 ); work?

Tags: javascript

I understand that Math.floor rounds the number to the lowest integer but when we do this: Math.random() * 10 wouldn't it multiply the number by 10 for example 9 * 10 = 90 so how would the number be between 1 and 10?

Thank you for helping I got the answer!

Answer (score 6):

`Math.random()` provides a random `number` from [`0`,`1`) (floating point: '[' = inclusive, ')' = exclusive).

So in `Math.floor( (Math.random() * 10) + 1);` multiplying `Math.random()` by `10` will provide a random number from [`0`, `10`).

The `+1` after the multiplication will change the output to be [`1`, `11`).

Then finally `Math.floor( ... )` converts the random number that is in the range from [`1`, `11`) to an integer value.

So the range of the executed statement will be all integers from [`1`, `10`]. Or to be more specific it will be one of the numbers in this set: { `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`, `10` }

Answer (score 3):

As it is stated in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)

> The Math.random() function returns a floating-point, pseudo-random
>   number in the range [0, 1[ that is, from 0 (inclusive) up to but not
>   including 1 (exclusive), which you can then scale to your desired
>   range. The implementation selects the initial seed to the random
>   number generation algorithm; it cannot be chosen or reset by the user.

That being said the minimum value of `Math.random()*10` is 0 while the upper exclusive bound is 10. Adding one to this expression result in a number in the range [1,11). Then by taking the Math.floor we take an integer number in range [0,10], since [Math.floor()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)

> returns the **largest** integer **less than or equal** to a given number.

Comment: Remember that the added 1 is for all numbers in the range so it will be from [1, 11) and the resulting integer range would be [1, 10] after the floor.

Answer (score 1):

Math.random method return a random number between 0 (inclusive) and 1 (exclusive). Which gives 0.9 * 10 = 9.

Answer (score 0):

By Google V8 Project:

> Math.random() Returns a Number value with positive sign, greater than
>   or equal to 0 but less than 1, chosen randomly or pseudo randomly with
>   approximately uniform distribution over that range, using an
>   implementation-dependent algorithm or strategy. This function takes no
>   arguments.

Math.random use an algorithm called [xorshift128+](http://vigna.di.unimi.it/ftp/papers/xorshiftplus.pdf)

Read More about [There's Math.random(), and then there's Math.random()](https://v8project.blogspot.in/2015/12/theres-mathrandom-and-then-theres.html)